# CSS compatibility issues on IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, extjs6, extjs6-classic

We are working on redesigning our web-based application’s Front-end. We started with a PoC based on Extjs 6 and we are facing few compatibility issues.
These compatibility issues are related to IE8 and CSS, while it is mentioned on your website that Extjs6 is fully compliant with IE8.

CSS classes work perfectly with all Major Web Browsers (Firefox, IE11, Chrome...) but some do not on IE8.

This is an example of CSS not working properly under IE8:

```
  Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
                text:'Button Test',
                cls: 'btnColor',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      });

  .btnColor {
        background-color: green;
        border-color:green;
   }
```

Works on IE11 :
[image]
But not on IE8 :
[image]

We would like to know if this is a known issue and is there a specific processing which allows us to handle this kind of needs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show me the output in html?

Comment: <span class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small" unselectable="on" data-ref="btnInnerEl" id="button-1009-btnInnerEl">btn</span>

this is what it looks like with firebug.

Comment: The html tag hasn't class "btnColor". Try to add "btnColor" class in your span.

Comment: It doesn't have 'btnColor' because it's the wrong tag; the relevant tag will be a few levels up in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Sencha support team:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305980-CSS-compatibility-issues-on-IE-8.&p=1118734#post1118734

This clarified a lot for me, it might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The element in your comment above is the wrong element - that's the inner element for the button; you want the class with an id something like `button-1009` (it's going to be an anchor or div tag a few elements up in the hierarchy).

And as to why it's not working - there are going to be multiple CSS selectors that define the background colour. The default one, from ExtJS, is going to be `x-btn-default-large`. The full CSS class for the attribute is going to be something like `x-btn buttonCls x-unselectable x-btn-default-large x-border-box`.

Done like that, both the `buttonCls` and `x-btn-default-large` are equally valid choices - the browser must pick one to use. IE8 is picking the last one; other browsers are picking the first one. Neither is wrong - the ambiguity is in your code.

To fix it, make your CSS selector more specific. Try:

```
.x-btn.buttonCls {
  background-color: green;
  border-color:green;
}
```

This applies to buttons (which will be the only things that have the `x-btn` componentCls attribute) that have the `buttonCls` cls attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your approach it works on firefox and not on ie8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is JavaScript syntax.

IE8 and earlier are strict about trailing commas on arrays and objects.

Your line `renderTo: Ext.getBody(),` ends in a comma, but is the last item in the object. In IE8, this will fail to compile.

The solution is simply to remove that comma.

You can keep an eye open for theses kinds of things by running your code through a linting tool like JSHint or ESLint, which will flag this kind if thing up.

Comment: Given that he does see a button, I suspect that the extraneous comma is just an artefact of preparing the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I removed the comma and still have the same problem.